# Where can I find the Windows version in a CIM instance?

Tags: windows, powershell, version, wmi, cim

On the Windows Settings > System > About page, the "Windows specifications" section presents the following information.

```
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version     20H2
OS build    19042.1288
```

Using the following reports the `Version` member as `19042.1288`.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_OperatingSystem').Version
```

Where can `20H2` be found in a CIM instance? I cannot find it in any of the following CIM instances.

```
CIM_OperatingSystem
Win32_OperatingSystem
Win32_SystemOperatingSystem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the **so-called *display version* - such as `"20H2"`** - doesn't seem to be a part of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) (`CIM_OperatingSystem` appears to be just an alias) and [`Win32_SystemOperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemoperatingsystem)  CIM (WMI) classes (as of Windows 10 20H2), but you can **obtain it *from the registry***:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' DisplayVersion
```

---

Similarly, the ***release ID* - such as `"2009"`** - is seemingly also only found in the registry:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' ReleaseId
```

Comment: Does adding a member to report the "so-called display version" to one or more CIM instances seem appropriate? If so, where would be the best place to ask for this? http://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell?

Comment: @lit, no, I don't think the PowerShell GitHub repo is the best place - PowerShell is just the messenger here. Perhaps you can try via the Feedback Hub app: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332

Comment: I have submitted an item on the Feedback Hub. However, I wonder if the request would carry more weight if the PowerShell team told the CIM/WMI team that they have users asking for it.

Comment: Good point, @lit:  You could create a PowerShell GitHub issue _too_, explaining the problem and referencing the feedback you've submitted (if there is something to link to) and how you submitted it; perhaps others will follow suit, possibly including PowerShell bigwigs.

Comment: You can easily convert the return value from  '(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_OperatingSystem').Version' to the display version you are after. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: @Mogash, please post an answer with code to "easily convert" from the CIM instance to the display version. I can think f some hard coded ways to do it. But, in general, hard coded is wrong coded.

Comment: @Mogash, the display version being sought here - e.g. `20H2` - isn't part of what `'(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_OperatingSystem').Version` returns, e.g. `19042.1288`.

Comment: @mklement0 yes I'm aware of that. I recommend using your approach getting the registry key. But if you for some reason have to use the Get-CimInstance command to get the value you can simply create a function to return the value to the display version. The full table of windows version history is publicly available at: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)

Comment: @Mogash, embedding static information (hard coded) into source code creates a perpetual maintenance cost. and risk. It seems likely that there will be future releases of Windows with new versioning labels. The code could fetch and parse the Wikipedia page but I do not know anyone that would consider that a reasonable or reliable thing to do.

Comment: @Mogash, I agree with lit's assessment, if that's indeed what you're suggesting - honestly, I'm still unclear on what you're actually suggesting.

Comment: @Mogash, please help me understand more clearly what you are suggesting. I am open to any better way to make it work.